# MongoDB $lookup in a single collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection that stores data for different types as below , all being individual documents

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "640e58c940bb4d036df16801"
  },
  "myLocalId": "id2a2",
  "title": "id2a2 title",
  "type": "type1",
  "subarray": [
    {
      "_id": "id2c2",
      "displayName": "id2c2 for id2a2",
      "type": "type2"
    },
    {
      "_id": "id2c4",
      "displayName": "id2c4 for id2a2",
      "type": "type2
    }
  ]
},
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "640e58f140bb4d036df16803"
  },
  "myLocalId": "id2a3",
  "type": "type1",
  "title": "id2a3 title3",
  "subarray": [
    {
      "_id": "id1c1",
      "displayName": "id1c1 for id2a3",
      "type": "type2"
    },
    {
      "_id": "id2c2",
      "displayName": "id2c2 for id2a3",
      "type": "type2"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "640e590d40bb4d036df16805"
  },
  "myLocalId": "id2a1",
  "type": "type1",
  "title": "id2a1 title",
  "subarray": [
    {
      "_id": "id2c2",
      "type": "type2",
      "displayName": "id2c2 for id2a1"
    }
  ]
}
```

and

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "640e59c540bb4d036df16808"
  },
  "myLocalId": "id1c1",
  "title": "id1c1 title",
  "type": "type2"
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "640e59da40bb4d036df1680a"
  },
  "myLocalId": "id2c2",
  "title": "id2c2 title3",
  "type": "type2"
}
```

I am trying to perform a lookup with documents of type = type2 being the source and type = type1 as the foreign collection where type2.myLocalId is the localField and documents of type = type1.subarray._id as the foreign key field.

As the first step, I am doing the match for type2 so that only those gets loaded

I am having difficulties in filtering the documents of type = type1 before the actual lookup operations starts.

The final output what I am expecting is something like this

```
 [{
 
  "myLocalId": "id1c1",
  "title": "id1c1 title",
  "type": "type2",
  "result": [
    {
      "myLocalId": "id2a3",
      "type": "type1",
      "title": "id2a3 title3",
      "subarray": [
        {
          "_id": "id1c1",
          "displayName": "id1c1 for id2a3",
          "type": "type2"
        },
        {
          "_id": "id2c2",
          "displayName": "id2c2 for id2a3",
          "type": "type2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},{
  "myLocalId": "id2c2",
  "title": "id2c2 title3",
  "type": "type1",
  "result": [
    {
      "myLocalId": "id2a2",
      "title": "id2a2 title",
      "type": "type1",
      "subarray": [
        {
          "_id": "id2c2",
          "displayName": "id2c2 for id2a2",
          "type": "type2"
        },
        {
          "_id": "id2c4",
          "displayName": "id2c4 for id2a2",
          "type": "type2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "myLocalId": "id2a3",
      "type": "type1",
      "title": "id2a3 title3",
      "subarray": [
        {
          "_id": "id1c1",
          "displayName": "id1c1 for id2a3",
          "type": "type2"
        },
        {
          "_id": "id2c2",
          "displayName": "id2c2 for id2a3",
          "type": "type2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
       
      "myLocalId": "id2a1",
      "type": "type1",
      "title": "id2a1 title",
      "subarray": [
        {
          "_id": "id2c2",
          "type": "type2",
          "displayName": "id2c2 for id2a1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}]
```

Comment: This sounds like it would be fairly straightforward with $match and $lookup, what is going wrong?

Comment: Can you add the query that you have tried so far?

Comment: @CharchitKapoor [
  {
    $match:
      /**
       * query: The query in MQL.
       */
      {
        type: "type2",
      },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "sameCollection2",
      localField: "myLocalId",
      foreignField: "subarray._id",
      as: "result",
    },
  },
]

Comment: @Joe This is what I have tried so far. But the pipeline does not filter the foreign collection
[{    $match:      {        type: "type2",      },  },{  from: "sameCollection2",  let: {        myLocalId: "$myLocalId",        myType: "$type"      },      pipeline: [        {          $match:             $expr: {    $and: [    {  $in: [ "$$myLocalId", "$subarray._id" ]  }, {
                  $in: [
                    "$$myType",
                    "$subarray.type"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
  as: "results",
}]

Comment: Please edit the question to add that, so it is more readable

Answer (score 1):

When the pipeline inside the lookup encounter a type1 document, the `$in` will be an error since the `$subarray._id` is missing.

You can filter those out of the inner pipeline with an additional match stage:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {type: "type2"}},
  {$lookup: {
      from: "collection",
      let: {
        myLocalId: "$myLocalId",
        myType: "$type"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {$match: {"subarray._id": {$ne: null}}},
        {$match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {$in: ["$$myLocalId","$subarray._id"]},
                { $in: ["$$myType","$subarray.type"]}
              ]
            }
        }}
      ],
      as: "results",      
  }}
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RongDwrQgYe)